# JDBC Connection connected but no query result to the resultset

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to do this project but it has a major problem.  I created table test2 with attribute cid.  I added a user into the cid by using these command line in the sql command line:

```
create table test2(cid varchar(20));
insert into test2 values('hello');

select cid from test2;
```

Then I get the result as

```
CID
-----------------------
HELLO
```

My question is that when I tried to use jdbc with eclipe to the server, I get rs.next() as false (rs is resultset). clearly I do have 'hello' inside the table test2.  Here is my code, if anyone could help me out with this, I would appreciate it:

```
public boolean connect(String username, String password)
{
    String connectURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbhost.xxx.xx.xxx.ca:1522:ug"; 

    try 
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectURL,username,password);
        System.out.println("\nConnected to Oracle!");
        ResultSet  rs;
        try
        {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT cid FROM test2");
            System.out.println("here");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("there");
                System.out.println("cid isssssssssss: " + rs.getString("cid"));

            }
            System.out.println("after here");
            stmt.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.print("Message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Message: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Connection is there because when I change cid into something else the sqlexception gave me an error message.  So it connects but not getting any query from the server.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT something FROM test2");

Connected to Oracle!
Message: ORA-00904: "SOMETHING": invalid identifier
```

Puzzling me.  Thanks again.

Comment: Have to ask: Did you commit your insert?

Comment: I added the insert via the sql command line and when I do select * from the command line all data came back ok.  But if I do select cid from test2 inside eclipse, it does not give me anything (rs.next() == false)

Comment: As rgettman suggests, the most likely explanation is that a `COMMIT` has not been issued on the transaction that did the INSERT. (We don't see any COMMIT performed.) Oracle prevents that row from being seen by any other sessions, until the change is committed, but the session that did the INSERT will "see" its own uncommitted changes.

Comment: try `select test2.cid from ug.test2` - maybe it is a permissions issue? - I think the relevant bits are in the error shown (invalid identifier) so either the table created has not been committed (see comments above) or the user does not have access to the table/schema (i.e. the credentials used to execute 'create table' are not the same used in the program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> I already have the data in the database. I did not insert data from the eclipse but instead I used .sql file to load it to the database. Will that need a commit as well?

I take it that you are using SQL*Plus to load data into the database.

If so, the `COMMIT` is required *unless* SQL*Plus is in "autocommit" mode.

```
sql*plus: SQL> show autocommit; 
          autocommit OFF 
          SQL> set autocommit ON;
```

(Without either "autocommit" or an explicit `COMMIT` statement, the transaction will be rolled back when you end the SQL*Plus session.  And that is the most likely explanation for what you are observing.)

Comment: Thank you! Not committing my inserts was the problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation for this behavior is that you did not issue a "`COMMIT;`" statement on the session that did the `INSERT`. (It's not shown.)

A `SELECT` query from that same session that did the INSERT will return the row. A session does "see" all of the uncommitted changes it has made. But Oracle prevents any other sessions from seeing those uncommitted changes, until they are committed.

What we want to see is:

```
SQL> insert into test2 values('hello');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

The inserted row will NOT be visible to other sessions until after a commit.

---

The other (much less likely) explanation is that the two sessions are connected to the database as different Oracle users, or are connected to different database instances.

Comment: I already have the data in the database. I did not insert data from the eclipse but instead I used .sql file to load it to the database. Will that need a commit as well?

Comment: Was there a `COMMIT` statement following the insert in the .sql file ? Was a `COMMIT` statement issued from the session that did the `INSERT`? (A SELECT statement issued from the same session that did the INSERT will return the row, but that does not mean that row is "in the database". Nothing is really "in the database" before the `COMMIT`. (Issue a `ROLLBACK` statement instead of a COMMIT, and see what the the SELECT statement returns.)

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange issue. Only missing part I could see is

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); statement in above code snippet. Can you please try putting it and see if there is any change in output.

Also please cross check the database where you created the entries is exactly same as the one specified in the code above.

Cheers